# I am getting internal server error 500 while hitting the url

Tags: http, plugins, websphere-liberty

ERROR:ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request rc=2 ws_common: websphereShouldHandleRequest: Config was successfully reloaded
025400da 00000809 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereGetStream: Failed to connect to app server on host

- ERROR: ws_common: websphereExecute: Failed to create the stream
  025400da 00000809 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to execute the transaction to
  025400da 00000809 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereWriteRequestReadResponse: Failed to find an app server to handle this request
  025400da 00000809 - ERROR: ws_common: websphereRequestHandler: Failed to find an app server to handle this request
  025400da 00000809 - ERROR:  ws_common: websphereHandleRequest: Failed to handle request rc=2
  025400da 00000809 -

Comment: What is the host and port listed in plugin-cfg.xml? Can you connect to it with wget or curl from your webserver? if you can't, the plugin can't either.

Comment: Same url running in root user but getting error in wasadmin user